# Azure - Load balancing multiple ports on same VM

Tags: azure, load-balancing

Can someone please suggest how to set up load balancer on Azure to load balance 2 docker containers running on 2 different ports of same VM.

I have an equivalent setup on AWS - Application Load Balancer. To achieve above goal, I can register each port as a different target on same target group of ALB.

EDIT: I am trying to add load balancing rule for a backend pool using multiple ports, but only one port is acceptable in a rule. Reason suggested is there can be only one rule for a frontend, protocol and port. How do I include multiple backend ports in same load balancing rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the load balancer and set the backend pool for the VM, and then create different probes and load balancer rules for different ports for the same backend pool which includes the VM.

Comment: I am trying to add load balancing rule for a backend pool using multiple ports, but only one port is acceptable in on rule @charles xu. I have edited main question with same details now.

Comment: @bvnbhati It's impossible. One rule only can include one port.

Comment: Ok, but then 2 rules with same frontend, protocol and port are also not allowed @Charles Xu 
I need port 80 on Load balancer to load balance 2 different port on same VM. How do I achieve that? I tried to do this using both Public Load Balancer and API gateway - but could not succeed.

Comment: @bvnbhati No, you can't. The load balancer rules cannot conflict with each other and one port only can include in one rule. One rule only can include one port.

Comment: is there any other way to achieve this goal - Load balancing of multiple ports on same VM?

Comment: @bvnbhati According to my knowledge, there is no way to achieve it. You only can create multiple rules with multiple ports.

Comment: `@Charles Xu I am NOT saying, I need to create 1 rule for multiple ports. All I am trying to achieve is 1 Public IP of load balancer is load balancing services on multiple ports of same VM. I don't mind adding multiple rules or any other added layer of components needed to achieve this target.
I already tried with multiple rule creation but second rule is not allowed to be added once I have added 1st rule with 1 port.

Comment: @bvnbhati Understand the sentence carefully. You only create multiple rules with different ports. What you want that one port for multiple ports for the backend VM is impossible.

Comment: Sorry for that @Charles XU - as I was able to achieve it on AWS so I thought, its only that I don't know how to do but it is doable. Thanks for the clarity on this.

Comment: @bvnbhati Well, if the answer is helpful to you please accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223346/discussion-between-bvnbhati-and-charles-xu).

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a fix for this? I am having the same issue

Comment: @bvnbhati: can you post your answer if you managed to do this?

Comment: @CharlesXu can you help me in this? When you said `create different probes and load balancer rules for different ports for the same backend pool which includes the VM` I did that, but how can I now access the services? Is it like `http://<lb-ip>:<frontend-port-of-lb-rule>` ? So that means I should specify the port in each http request? Because last time I checked, it doesn't allow me to have same frontend port for multiple rules